# Can different entities of the same kind have different parents in Google ndb at the same time? If yes, how is this useful?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

During the declaration of the model class, there are no restrictions for adding the parent key:

```
class Employee():
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)

class Address():
    city = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)

class Education():
    college = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

The current way in which we add the ancestor path is during the write to the Datastore as shown below

```
employee = Employee()
employee.put()

address1 = Address(parent=employee)
```

So, there is nothing that  prevents from one doing:

```
address1 = Address(parent=employee)
address2 = Address(parent=education)
```

which sorta feels wierd!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they can - the parent can literally be an entity of any kind (or `None` - standalone entities, AKA entity group owners).

You example is exactly one such type of usage.

As for the usability it really depends on the application. If you find it useful, it is :) If not - you're probably not gonna use it.

For example your app might also have entities for businesses or colleges/universities, which would all have at least one `Address` child entity associated with them.

Side notes:

- you should have your classes inherit the `ndb.Model` class to make their instances ndb entities:

  ```
  class Address(ndb.Model):
  ```
- you should pass the parent entity's **key** in the child creation, not the parent entity itself:

  ```
  address1 = Address(parent=employee.key)
  ```

Comment: Ah, yes. I agree with the side notes. Somehow overlooked them. But, the question I meant to ask is whether two different entities of the same kind can have different parents at the same time? (Have edited the question as well)

Comment: Yep - that's what the answer is really for (apart for the notes).